# How do you find the usable storage space

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage, clariion

How do I calculate the "Total Usable Storage Size" in clariion -Cx3 20C (I'm little confused here on how to proceed with the calculation)? I have the raw storage size from the disk summary (included the hot spare).I know the used storage size ,calculated from storage group.

I need to calculate the total available storage size = Total usable storage size- Used storage size.

How do  you calculate the total usable storage size?

**Note:** Do I need to go to `Array` > `R click` > `Bind Lun` and then look for free capacity under each raid group?

How do I go for celerra?

*I do not have ECC enabled.

Comment: Wildchild - please don't use the moderator flag simply because your question hasn't been answered for 12 hours - if you need urgent responses to your questions perhaps you should get support contracts for your various SAN parts - SF has no guaranteed service, plus when you mod-flag a question you only alert about 6 people so it's hardly a tactic that's going to work well either.

Comment: @chopper- I am really sorry for using the Flag. I 'll be careful from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to look at the properties of each RAID group to see how much space has been used on each RAID Group.

You can also get this info with the naviseccli from the command line.

```
NaviSecCli -h {ServerName} getrg
```